Jenkins completed jobs changing status from success (green) to failure (red) overnight
I have a strange issue on Jenkins which reproduces itself systematically.
Completed jobs in green status are found the next day with a red status with the same build number, and several details are lost, such as the duration (0ms instead of 25min), the Jenkins node (it shows "built-in" instead of the actual node name), and the repository details (revision, repository URL).
The Jenkins job is just a Gradle build finishing with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" in the log.
I removed all the plugins from the job to make sure it was not due to a plugin.


See also this question of mine. I suspect the issue might be due to some server-side housekeeping.
